# How can I update an email address in meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, email, meteor

Hi I am building an app using Meteor and need to update my email address. I am using the Meteor accounts package.

My form passes an email value into an accountDetails object, which I will pass into a method to update my profile (including my email):

```
Meteor.users.update({_id: this.userId},
{
   $set: {
            'emails.$.address': accountsDetail.email
    }

});
```

This gives me the error:

```
Exception while invoking method 'saveAccountInfo' MongoError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpanded update: emails.$.address
```

Here is my user schema:

```
{
"_id" : "12345",

"emails" : [
    {
        "address" : "abc123@gmail.com",
        "verified" : false
    }
```

Can someone help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: whats the problem with that code?

Comment: hi - i just updated my question to include the error

Comment: i THINK since emails is an array, the code doesn't correctly locate the index of my email

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure the user has one address, which should be the case you can use `emails.0.address` instead of `emails.$.address`.

This should work for nearly all use cases. The exception is when there are many emails associated with a user. In this case:

If you are on the server & only on the server, you can use the positional operator to update a specific email, if there are multiple addresses. You need to, in this case specify the current email in the query portion of the update. I.e: `{_id: this.userId, 'emails.$.address' : <current address> }`

The `$` positional update operator is not currently available on the mongo client in Meteor.

Answer (score 1):

as each user is able to have multiple addresses (it´s an array - see http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users for details) you need to specify which key you want to update (in this case the key is the address itself)

```
Meteor.users.update({_id: this.userId, "emails.address":"me@domain.com"},
$set:{'emails.$.address': accountsDetail.email}
});
```

If every user only has one email you could also think about dropping this one and inserting the new one. see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/ for details.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

René